# How to save session of dropbox api in android

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I am uploading a file in the dropbox using dropbox api in android. I have successfully uploaded file in the dropbox but problem is that each time i need to allow the access of dropbox. Each time i have to go to the browser and allow the access.
I dont know how to solve this issue.
I have used these codes to upload files in dropbox:

```
public class DropboxFileUploadMainForContact extends Activity {
private static final int TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
 final String DIR = "/";
private File f;
private boolean mLoggedIn, onResume;
public DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mApi;
String upload_filepath = "abc/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // get the file which we want to upload
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    upload_filepath = upload_filepath + b.getString("fileNameToUpload");

    AndroidAuthSession session = buildSession();
    mApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);

    setLoggedIn(false);

    createDir();
    if (mLoggedIn) {
        logOut();
    }
    if (Utils.isOnline(DropboxFileUploadMainForContact.this)) {
        mApi.getSession().startAuthentication(DropboxFileUploadMainForContact.this);
        onResume = true;
    } else {
        Utils.showNetworkAlert(DropboxFileUploadMainForContact.this);
        finish();
    }




}

private AndroidAuthSession buildSession() {
    AppKeyPair appKeyPair = new AppKeyPair(Constants.DROPBOX_APP_KEY,
            Constants.DROPBOX_APP_SECRET);
    AndroidAuthSession session;

    String[] stored = getKeys();
    if (stored != null) {
        AccessTokenPair accessToken = new AccessTokenPair(stored[0],
                stored[1]);
        session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair, Constants.ACCESS_TYPE,
                accessToken);
    } else {
        session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair, Constants.ACCESS_TYPE);
    }

    return session;
}

private String[] getKeys() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
            Constants.ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
    String key = prefs.getString(Constants.ACCESS_KEY_NAME, null);
    String secret = prefs.getString(Constants.ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, null);
    if (key != null && secret != null) {
        String[] ret = new String[2];
        ret[0] = key;
        ret[1] = secret;
        return ret;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

private void logOut() {
    mApi.getSession().unlink();

    clearKeys();
}

private void clearKeys() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
            Constants.ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
    Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.clear();
    edit.commit();
}

private void createDir() {
    File dir = new File(Utils.getPath());
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO) {
            // f = new File(Utils.getPath() + "/temp.jpg");
            if (Utils.isOnline(DropboxFileUploadMainForContact.this)) {
                mApi.getSession().startAuthentication(
                        DropboxFileUploadMainForContact.this);
                onResume = true;
            } else {
                Utils.showNetworkAlert(DropboxFileUploadMainForContact.this);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
    mLoggedIn = loggedIn;
    if (loggedIn) {
        // new
        // Now make a backup file of sms
        // BackUpAllSms();

        DropboxFileUpload uploadFile = new DropboxFileUpload(this, mApi,
                DIR, upload_filepath);
        uploadFile.execute();

        onResume = false;
        finish();

    }
}





private void storeKeys(String key, String secret) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
            Constants.ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
    Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.putString(Constants.ACCESS_KEY_NAME, key);
    edit.putString(Constants.ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, secret);
    edit.commit();
}

private void showToast(String msg) {
    Toast error = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    error.show();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    try {
        AndroidAuthSession session = mApi.getSession();

        Log.d("ppp", "session.authenticationSuccessful() on resume = "+session.authenticationSuccessful());
        if (session.authenticationSuccessful()) {
            try {
                session.finishAuthentication();

                TokenPair tokens = session.getAccessTokenPair();
                storeKeys(tokens.key, tokens.secret);
                setLoggedIn(onResume);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                showToast("Couldn't authenticate with Dropbox:"
                        + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

}

Could anyone tell me how to solve this issue??

Comment: The call to `startAuthentication` is what starts the auth process. If you're surprised that the auth process is starting, start by looking at when you're calling `startAuthentication` and investigate the logic around that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid having to authorize the app to connect to the user's Dropbox account manually each time (i.e., calling `startAuthentication`), the app should store and re-use the resulting access token, so that this only needs to be done once.

It seems you already have code to do this in `buildSession`, using `storeKeys` and `getKeys`, which use `SharedPreferences` to persist the access token.

So, you just need to know if the `AndroidAuthSession` already has an access token loaded. You can use the `AndroidAuthSession.isLinked` method for this:

https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/session/AbstractSession.html#isLinked()

Call that before calling `startAuthentication` so you can know if you already have an access token.